# Python how to make a socket server use a command built into the client

Tags: python, sockets

I have client and a server if the client has a command that for say just prints out Hello World how would i run that command but in the server code? the hello world code should be like this

```
if data == "hello":
  print("Hello World!")
```

sorry if you don't understand my question I am not good at explaining things

Comment: How is your server set up? Do you use flask? More info is needed for us to help you

Comment: I am using threads and sockets if that helps

Comment: Can you please be more specific, for example by editing your question and posting the code relevant to your server.

Comment: Well i cant post the code because thats the issue as i said i need to make my server use a command in the client code which is a completely different file

Comment: Oh! Do you mean, for example, that you've defined `def foo(bar): return bar` in the client code and you need the server to access the `foo()` function?

Comment: Yes that exactly it any idea?

Comment: Just one more question, do you want the server to execute the function, or just tell the client to execute the function?

Comment: i want the server to tell the client to use the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the info you've given me, and no code, this is the best I could come up with:

## Server code:

```
# client gives data to server    
if data == "hello":
      return "func" # use whatever method you already do to send this as a response to the user
```

## Client code

```
import sys

# ...

def func(): # note this is the same name as what the server returns
    print("Hello world!")

# ...

response = <response from server> # you should know how it gets this, but this should (in this example) be 'func'

this_module = sys.modules[__name__]

getattr(this_module, response)() # this line executes the function, and will print "Hello world!"
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @ZerefDragneel If the answer helped, please consider upvoting it so more people can find the answer if they have the same problem

Comment: btw their is only one issue and that is when i check the client it automatically says hello world and i wanted to make it so the server has to have a command to make it say hello world

Comment: @ZerefDragneel Oh ok, you prior comment said 'i want the server to tell the client to use the function', so i assumes you wanted the client to execute it. Now, does the server have a specific set of functions that it can run or do you want to be able to send **any** function that you send it?

Comment: okay so basically i want the client to have the code to run but i want the server to have a command to run the code in client

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the server to be able to run a command on the client's machine?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible for a server to directly run code on a client's machine. What exactly is wrong with my answer? It gets the server to run a command on the client's machine right?

Comment: it runs the code automatically i need the server to be able to do it manually like a command also i have code made in C that does what i need but sadly i cant read C so i cant understand it

Comment: @ZerefDragneel Please post the C code in your answer or give a link to it so that I may read it and decipher what you want.

Comment: The C code does exactly what I outlined in my explanation, but instead, in the code I assume the client is always checking what the server is returning, which is beyond the scope of this question. If you want an answer to that part of the question (i.e. how to make the client constantly check for messages from the server), please open a different question.

Comment: What do i ask in the new question

Comment: You could for example ask (while providing code and an accurate description of what you want): "How do I make a client constantly check for different responses from a server?"